# Erro com classe php Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function run_search()

Tags: php, classes

To tentado criar uma classe, e to obtendo o erro abaixo já pesquisei mais ainda não encontrei o por que está dando este erro.

Erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function run_search() in D:\xampp\htdocs\Github\astra\class\buscaAnimes.class.php:17 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\Github\astra\index.php(11): buscaAnimes->get_busca('21') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Github\astra\class\buscaAnimes.class.php on line 17
```

Class::

```
    <?php

    class buscaAnimes{

    private $idAnime;
    private $urlMal;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    //Pega a id passada pelo usuario e atribui ao $idAnime
    public function get_busca($b){
        $this->idAnime = $b;
        $resposta = run_search();
        return $resposta;
    }

    private function run_search(){
        if(!isset($this->idAnime) & empty($this->idAnime)){
            return 'Erro: É necessario um id para fazer a busca';
        }

        $this->urlMal = 'https://exemplo.com/anime/'. $this->idAnime .'/';

       $resposta = curlSearch($this->urlMal,'get');

       if($resposta[1] != 200){
           return $resposta[1];
       }else{
           $resposta = $resposta[0];
           return $resposta;
       }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro quer dizer que não existe uma função `run_search`, o que existe é a função `run_search` dentro da classe `buscaAnimes`, faltou adicionar o `$this->`:

```
//Pega a id passada pelo usuario e atribui ao $idAnime
public function get_busca($b){
    $this->idAnime = $b;
    $resposta = $this->run_search();
    return $resposta;
}
```

Comment: Entendi, Testei e funcionou. Brigado!